# objective-c json parser: How to parse a json file starting with a string and not brackets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have a JSON file looking like this:

```
test.Data({
  "field": "try", 
  "date": "20150501", 
  "data": [
    "<sample1 code_date=\"2015050110\" type=\"play\"><sample2 name=\"foo\" place=\"bar\">"]
});
```

I tried reading it using:

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"localhost"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlAsString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil)
        _textLabel.stringValue = @"Good";
    else if ([data length] == 0 && connectionError == nil)
        _textLabel.stringValue = @"Nothing to load";
    else if (connectionError != nil)
        _textLabel.stringValue = connectionError.userInfo[@"NSLocalizedDescription"];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSError *e = nil;
        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error: &e];

        if (!jsonArray) {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
        } else {
            for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
                NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
            }
        }
    });
```

But I get the following error:

> Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x61800006e880 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Any idea how I could read this JSON format into Xcode using the standard JSON parser?

Comment: The contents of the file is not a valid JSON, looks more like a method call.

Comment: Update the server to return valid JSON.

Comment: Why do you use `dispatch_async` to run that code on another background thread when the `NSURLConnection` request completion handler is already being run on a background thread?

Comment: I am new to this method and I am still reading about it. This part of the code comes from a tutorial. I guess it is not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to strip the method call and keep only the passed JSON argument. If you're sure that the file contains only a method call, and no other code, especially one with curly braces, you can apply the following logic: find the first and the last curly brace, and use that substring:

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger firstCurlyBracePos = [dataString rangeOfString:@"{" options:0].location;
NSUInteger lastCurlyBracePos = [dataString rangeOfString:@"}" options: NSBackwardsSearch].location;
NSString jsonString = nil;
if(firstCurlyBracePos != NSNotFound && lastCurlyBracePos != NSNotFound) {
    jsonString = [dataString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(firstCurlyBracePos, lastCurlyBracePos-firstCurlyBracePos)];
}
```

`jsonString` will hold the `JSON` part of the file, or `nil` if at least one of the two curly braces was not found.